# Can evil-visual-block show inserted text on all lines like string-rectangle does?

Tags: evil

In regular (non-evil) emacs, if you select a rectangular region and hit `C-x r t` to run `string-rectangle`, inserted text is displayed on all the selected lines as you type.

In Vim, if you select a visual-block and hit `I`, inserted text is only displayed on the top line until you finish by hitting `Escape`, at which point it inserts the text on all *non-empty* lines.

I was really hoping that evil-mode would combine the best of both worlds: select a rectangular region, hit `I`, and inserted text is displayed on all non-empty lines as you type. Unfortunately, it doesn't display the text as you type.

Is there a way to either make `evil-insert` display inserted text on all non-empty lines or get `string-rectangle` to respect empty lines?

*Edit*: I just realized there's also `string-insert-rectangle`, which is like visual-block `I`, in that it inserts text along the left edge of the rectangle, whereas `string-rectangle` is more like visual-block `s` because it replaces the existing contents of the rectangle with inserted text.

`string-insert-rectangle` also doesn't show the final results in the buffer until you complete your input, which makes me wonder if there's a reason behind this I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I well understood `evil`'s source code, it's a matter of implementation. When you hit `I` with a visual block, the variable `evil-insert-vcount` is set to the number of lines in that block (and column start position etc.), so evil knows how many times to repeat on those extra lines below the insertion that just started. *But*, this extra insertion takes place only when exiting from insert state - see function `evil-cleanup-insert-state` (the only place `evil-insert-vcount` is actually used). For reference, here's the function description:

> "Called when Insert state is about to be exited.
>   Handles the repeat-count of the insertion command."

(where repeat-count refers to both [evil-insert-]`count` and `vcount`).

I know this isn't an actual *answer*, in that I have no idea how and what to modify to make it work as you suggest. Maybe the right place to ask *this* question would be at the official's [evil issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues?status=new&status=open) - I know there are many elisp-fu conaisseurs here, but few of them are probably also interested in evil-mode, at least at this level.